# Discord.py bot: Filter commands for specific user

Tags: python, discord, bots

does anyone know, how I can give only one specific user acces to a command?

Comment: check for the user's name and id everytime the command is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def commandname(ctx):
if ctx.author.id == 'usersID': 
   # do something 
else: 
  await ctx.send(f"Sorry you can't do that.")
```